# How can i join two table in Linq and display the join to Data GridView?

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I'm trying to join two tables and to display the Join result into GridView in WinForms, but something is going wrong...

it's not giving me Error message or something, Please help!!

my code :

```
var temp = teacherCmbBx.SelectedItem.ToString();

var temp2 = (from c in context.Teachers
             where temp == c.FirstName
             select c).ToList();
long num = temp2[0].ID;

var teacherGroup = (from t in context.Teachers
                    join g in context.Groups on t.ID equals g.TeacherID
                    where num == t.ID
                    select t);

teachergrpGridView.DataSource = teacherGroup;

string temp3 = (string)teachergrpGridView.Rows[rowNum].Cells[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You are just missing `.ToList()`

```
var teacherGroup = (from t in context.Teachers
                    join g in context.Groups on t.ID equals g.TeacherID
                    where num == t.ID
                    select t).ToList();

teachergrpGridView.DataSource = teacherGroup;
```

Comment: Don't you have to call DataBind() afterwards as well ?

Comment: @CheGueVerra Its `WinForms` and I don't think its required (I am not sure)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var teacherGroup = from t in context.Teachers
                                join g in context.Groups on t.ID equals g.TeacherID
                                where num == t.ID
                                select new {
                                  t.Id ,
                                  g.Name,
                                  t.xxxx 
                                 };
```